# Azure Application Gateway X-Forwaded-For

Tags: azure, azure-application-gateway

When setting up Azure Application Gateway to act as a reverse proxy is it possible to stop the `x-forwarded-for` header being included when forwarding requests so that the original client IP is hidden?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No this is currently not supported. The X-Forwarded-For is always inserted.